# Android WebView not providing all request headers

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I want to read all headers that an android `WebView` puts in requests, so I have override `shouldInterceptRequest` function an inside of it I printed all request headers, just for testing.

```kotlin
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
    request.requestHeaders.forEach {
        Log.d("header", "Header: $it")
    }
    return null
}
```

It should have printed all headers, but some, `cookie` in particular, are missing. What is happening here?